# Raspberry Pi 4: Wifi working but applications cannot manage it

Tags: networking, raspberrypi

I'm facing a strange behavior on my Raspberry Pi 4 with Ubuntu 20.04: wifi works editing the network.config file but I cannot manage it with NetworkManager or the network widget on KDE.
I'm missing some configurations?

Comment: I believe it is managed with netplan and networkd...

I think you would have to change the "renderer" to NetworkManager...

but there are so many different variations of ubuntu configs on pi, it is hard to tell...

these describe both...

https://medium.com/@huobur/how-to-setup-wifi-on-raspberry-pi-4-with-ubuntu-20-04-lts-64-bit-arm-server-ceb02303e49b

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/change-netplan-renderer-from-networkd-to-networkmanager/

I just used netplan and config'd it in the yaml because I don't have a graphical desktop running.

Comment: And if you have to use apps like Cockipt how can you manage the network? It cannot see wlan0.

Comment: I struggled with my Pi's network connection... Doing the research and finding out how many different iso's were downloadable and different versions of the same releases was exhausting... when I finally found one that lined up.. i just went with netplan and called it a day... And i STILL have a problem with it... Now I see you are referring to "additional" applications, i'm not sure those links are what you need to make it "visible". I thought those links might get you to where it could help you with NetworkManager.